# Combining multiple sources for jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am wondering how can I combine 2 sources together using the jquery autocomplete? 
What I hope to achieve is having the results "chocolate biscuits", "strawberry biscuits", "peanut biscuits" and so on.. then it will loop to swiss roll and start the flavours all over again: "chocolate swiss roll", "strawberry swiss roll", "peanut swiss roll", etc. 
When user type the word: "chocolate", all the food values will appear in the autocomplete. However I can't seem to get the results I want.
Here is my code:

```
<script>
var food= [
    "biscuits",
    "swiss roll",
    "bread",
    "waffle",
    "cookies"
];

var flavours= [
    "chocolate",
    "strawberry",
    "peanut",
    "cheese",
    "green tea",
    "vanilla"
];

var mergedResults;

for (i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < flavours.length; j++) {
        mergedResults = food[i].concat(flavours[j]);
    }
}

$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: mergedResults
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be

```
var mergedResults = [];

for (i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < flavours.length; j++) {
        mergedResults.push(food[i].concat(" ", flavours[j]));
    }
}
```